# Is it possible to transfer money from PayPal account to a bank account or credit card?

Tags: api, paypal

I am using future paypal payment method for payment

I want to transfer money from paypal account to bank or credit card using paypal access token.

But i can't find any proper way to do this.

Is there any method for that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no API's available to automate this programatically, but you can "withdrawal" money from PayPal into your bank account manually from within the PayPal account profile.

If you want to send PayPal funds to a credit card, the best way to do that would be to get a PayPal debit card for your account, and then use that to submit a payment to your credit card company.

Comment: Is there any way to transfer money from paypal to bank account using paypal api?

Comment: "There are no API's available to automate this programatically" = "there is no way to transfer money from paypal to bank account using paypal api"

Comment: why the heck won't paypal create 1 then? got some clients that don't really trust paypal, and want the money paid to their paypal account withdrawn asap (to their bank, which they trust), now i can't automate this process for them x.x

Comment: @hanshenrik, Just have them call PayPal and request that they turn on the auto-sweep feature, where it automatically moves their entire PayPal balance to their bank account at the end of each day.

Comment: in this year. is this still correct? is there no new api out there?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, still correct.  No API to withdrawal funds out of PayPal.

Comment: @DrewAngell Still there is no way to withdraw money from paypal account via paypal api

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Unfortunately, that's correct.  However, you could give them a call and request that they turn on "auto sweep" on your account.  This would automatically move the balance of your account to your bank at the end of each day.

Comment: if i am a bank and i want my customer's account numbers to be available for usage inside paypal accounts how i can do this? also how can i provide my bank customers the ability to transfer money from the bank apps to other people's paypal accounts?