# Automatically transfer money from one bank account to another

Tags: api, paypal, backend, banking, payu

Is there available any API which allow us to automatically transfer money to other bank account? I only found that I can't have it done with [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978238/is-it-possible-to-transfer-money-from-paypal-account-to-a-bank-account-or-credit) API.

I have user money on one bank account and after some action in application I need to transfer this money to other user bank account.

So to summary it all, step by step:

- User1 send money to application bank account.
- After few hours User1 confirm some action on aplication by clicking button.
- After User1 clicked button I want to transfer money to User2 bank account from application bank account automatically.

I already have in DB every information needed to do bank transfer.

I am looking for API which would allow me to do third step which is automatically transfering money from my (app) bank account to user bank account no matter which bank he is using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We finally end with using payu API. http://developers.payu.com/en/payouts.html#payouts_payout_creation_on_account_given

But it's limitted only to businesses which generate over 100k PLN (around 20k EUR) money turnover monthly.

---

Good alternative tho is revolut. Their API can handle payout to clients but is not responsible for receiving payments.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this api

[Money Transfer API](https://www.pay2all.in/money-transfer-api)

Answer (score 0):

If you current bank doesn't support this feature (yet) there is no way to do this without switching to another bank.

I don't know if you are lucky enough to be located in The Netherlands. If you are, then you can use Bunq. They offer a nice APIs and SDKs that makes this possible.
Here are the details: https://www.bunq.com/nl/developer

I think there are plans to extend this to the rest of EU soon.